# Triggering a UIButton's method when user drags finger into button's area?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I want to have a button that triggers its method under the following conditions:

- When the user taps the button
- When the user presses the button and drags his/her finger out of the button's area
- When the user drags his/her finger from outside the button's area to inside the button's area

Basically, anytime any part of the button is touched, regardless of origin of touch, I want the method triggered, but want to accomplish this by manipulating UIButton properties, like `touchedUpInside` and such.

Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: You need to add `UIGestureRecognizer` to your `UIButton`. Show us what you have tried so far ?

Comment: I have tried using UIGestureRecognizers. I didn't like their response because I don't want to detect swipes and such. Even if the user only moves their finger 5 pixels, from just outside of the button to just inside, I want this detected.

Comment: try looking into hittest method of a view you can manipulate all the touch events inside it

Comment: Could you post some sample code? I didn't understand how to implement hitTest for this purpose

Comment: Is it necessary to trigger the event only when touch is dragged from outside the button to inside or vice versa? Or should it just fire up as soon as the button is touched(may it move from out to in or in to out)?

Comment: @jake9115 You figure anything out here?

Answer (score 3):

Regarding:

> - When the user presses the button and drags his/her finger out of the button's area

I recently have done something similar. Here is my code in **Swift**.

(In this example you subclassed UIButton, like: `class FadingButton: UIButton`)

```
...

// The user tapped the button and then moved the finger around.
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)

    // Get the point to which the finger moved
    if let point: CGPoint = touches.first?.location(in: self) {

        // If the finger was dragged outside of the button...
        if ((point.x < 0 || point.x > bounds.width) ||
            (point.y < 0 || point.y > bounds.height)) {

            // Do whatever you need here
        }
    }
}
...
```

I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

Make you method such as `-(IBAction)btnTap` and connect to these properties

- When the user taps the button. - Use `Touch Down` method for this
- When the user presses the button and drags his/her finger out of the
  button's area -  Use `Touch Up Inside` for this purpose
- When the user drags his/her finger from outside the button's area to
  inside the button's - `Touch Drag Inside`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following UIControlEvents to your button:

1. `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`
2. `UIControlEventTouchDragOutside`
3. `UIControlEventTouchDragInside`

as such

```
    [self.myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dragMoving:withEvent: )
              forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDragInside | UIControlEventTouchDragOutside];

    [self.myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dragEnded:withEvent: )
              forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside |
     UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];

    [self.myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonTouchDown:withEvent: )
              forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown];
```