# Highlight continues when touch outside of button in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, highlight

My question is that i have a UIButton inside my app. When touch it and move my finger outside of button, highlighting continues to specific points around it and then returns back to normal.

My expectation is that when i go to outside of button boundary it should return back to normal immediately.

Do you have any idea for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to target drag event  when drags fingers goes out side the boundary of the button it should release the content and  here you can check  dragoutside event

[Triggering a UIButton's method when user drags finger into button's area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17077889/triggering-a-uibuttons-method-when-user-drags-finger-into-buttons-area)