# How to trigger UIButton event when finger is dragged from 1 button to the next

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

This is a simple Xylophone app from a tutorial that i am following.
If we press on each button, a new note is played. It works fine.
But when i want to swipe from 1 button to another, there is no sound.

Github link for the complete project:
https://github.com/jaineelesh/Xylophone

i have tried with the Touch Drag Enter/Exit/Inside/Outside also, but nothing seems to work for me.

Please help.

**ViewController.swift file**

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController{

var player: AVAudioPlayer?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func noteOnDrag(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // selecting the correct note based on the tag
    //playSound(tag: sender.tag)
    print("enter")
}

@IBAction func noteOnDragExit(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Exit")
}

@IBAction func notePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // selecting the correct note based on the tag
    //playSound(tag: sender.tag)
}

func playSound(tag: Int) {
    let note = "note" + String(tag)
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: note, withExtension: "wav") else { return }

    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.wav.rawValue)

        guard let player = player else { return }

        player.play()
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

And this is how the app looks.
[image]

I am a beginner so my knowledge is very limited. I tried to find the solutions but there are none which explains how to solve my problem with swift 4. If there exists some old solution, then i am not able to understand them. 
i tried to use the below events but they don't seem to work.
[image]

Comment: You might be better off doing these with UIControls and not with UIButtons. It might be a bit more difficult to set them up, as it would be through the storyboard, but making a custom UIControl class and placing them on your view controller might be a cleaner solution. They have a draggedInto method that will fire and you can pass that back to your view controller so as to play the sound that you want to play.

Comment: From a musical point of view, the functionality you are looking for and have described is called a “glissando” (swiping or dragging from one button/key to the next. It might be worth looking up “How to Glissando” in code/programming/swift etc. I am also trying to add some functionality: 1) playChords (e.g. four fingers, four taps, four notes at once. Four mediaPlayer instances (create and release, re-using four media player instances) 2) noteNames toggle on and off (e.g. IB boolean switch true/false for button.text) If you have any luck or ideas for this, do let me know. Best wishes, Tony Urba

Answer (score 1):

You have connected event `Touch Up Inside` thats why pressing works (your `notePressed` function). If you want your code to work also with swiping then try connecting `Touch Drag Exit` or `Touch Drag Enter` events.

On your last screen select that event and drag it onto

```
@IBAction func notePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // selecting the correct note based on the tag
    //playSound(tag: sender.tag)
}
```

Events names are self-describing but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11390048/9865234) you can also find explanation

//EDIT:
 Ok, I probably did not understand you at first.
 I think that your problem is similar to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16661496/9865234).

The idea:

1. Make an outlet collection that contains all your buttons.

   ```
   @IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!
   ```
2. Use `touchesMoved` method (example):

   ```
   override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
       super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
       guard let touch = event?.allTouches?.first else {return}
       let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self.view)
       buttons.forEach { (button) in
           if button.frame.contains(touchLocation) {
               print(button.tag)
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: already did that with the drag enter/exit action events. but nothing happens. I used a print() statement but it never gets called when i swipe from 1 button to other.

Comment: Hi helps but very slightly and doesn't do what exactly i am looking for.
Few Issues that i am facing with your above solution:
1. It only works when i swipe from outside the button to the button. Doesn't work if i swipe from 1 button to button.
2. even while i am moving inside the button, the note keeps on playing, But that is contrary to the idea of a xylophone key press because, if a key is pressed, there should 1 sound till i release the button. But here when i even move inside the button, it give new sound.